SQL Query CASE Clause when > 180 days between TransactionDate for same MemberNumber
probably a simple request but a rookie like me can't seem to figure it out.
I just need a query that generates results when there is > 180 days between the TransactionDate for each MemberNumber.  This is what I have so far but it's not working correctly:
SELECT [TransactionDate]
  ,[MemberNumber]
  ,[MemberName]
  ,[PrincipalAmount]
  ,[TransactionCategory]
  ,[TransactionChannel]
  ,[Service]
  ,[Product]
  ,
  
CASE 
WHEN DATEDIFF(day, TransactionDate, TransactionDate) > 180 
AND MemberNumber = MemberNumber THEN 'Dormant'
ELSE 'Active'
END AS Dormant_Flag


Please tag your DBMS (sql server, postgres, etc) as date functions vary. Adding a few rows of minimally reproducible sample data (formatted text) will help. Your sample data will not need all those columns in this case.

And don't forget to specify the expected result, i.e. provide a complete [mcve].

I'm always sceptical when I read such requirements like 180 days. That's often incorrect and just done because people think it's simpler and don't know how to check for 6 months. So do really want 180 days or rather 6 months?

Using Lag() you can obtain the previous Transaction date for a MemberNumber
SELECT [TransactionDate]
  ,[MemberNumber]
  ,[MemberName]
  ,[PrincipalAmount]
  ,[TransactionCategory]
  ,[TransactionChannel]
  ,[Service]
  ,[Product]
  , LAG(TransactionDate) OVER (Partition BY [MemberNumber] ORDER BY TransactionDate) as PreviousTransactionDate
  ,DATEDIFF(Day, LAG(TransactionDate) OVER (Partition BY [MemberNumber] ORDER BY TransactionDate) , TransactionDate) as diff
  
,CASE 
WHEN DATEDIFF(Day, LAG(TransactionDate) OVER (Partition BY [MemberNumber] ORDER BY TransactionDate) , TransactionDate) > 180 
THEN 'Dormant'
ELSE 'Active'
END AS Dormant_Flag
FROM Example

fiddle



TransactionDate
MemberNumber
MemberName
PrincipalAmount
TransactionCategory
TransactionChannel
Service
Product
PreviousTransactionDate
diff
Dormant_Flag




2024-01-01
1
Bob
1
1
1
1
1
null
null
Active


2024-01-03
1
Bob
1
1
1
1
1
2024-01-01
2
Active


2024-02-03
1
Bob
1
1
1
1
1
2024-01-03
31
Active


2024-06-03
1
Bob
1
1
1
1
1
2024-02-03
121
Active


2024-01-03
2
Ann
1
1
1
1
1
null
null
Active


2024-09-04
2
Ann
1
1
1
1
1
2024-01-03
245
Dormant




Wow this worked!!!  I have a lot to reverse engineer from this in order to learn exactly why it works but thank you!!  Exactly what I needed
